# MySQL 1064 error for alter table

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

This is driving me nuts, I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is the query passed in mysqli_query:

```
ALTER TABLE `lc_products` ADD `default_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AFTER `sold_out_status_id`;
```

This is the fatal error that PHP throws:

```
Fatal error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `lc_products` ADD `default_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AFTER `s' at line 1
```

The exact same query works when inserted into phpMyAdmin.

Using XAMP for Windows with PHP 5.4 + MySQL 5.5.4.

Does anyone know what's going on, or what is wrong?

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE `lc_products` ADD `default_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AFTER `sold_out_status_id`;";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or $this->_error($query, mysqli_errno($link), mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: What is `$query` contains ?

Comment: weird, check if you already have the column in the table and query is getting failed.

Comment: Found the error. There is a hidden byte character in front of the word ALTER. Detected and debugged by var_dump($query).

Comment: Ah that was painful :)

Comment: Yes, but nailed it! I started to think this was a mysqli bug at first. Thanks for helping out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the semi-colon from your query.

```
 $query = "ALTER TABLE `lc_products` ADD `default_category_id` int(11) 
           NOT NULL AFTER `sold_out_status_id`";
```

Answer (score 0):

Illegal byte character.

I used var_dump() to debug the query string and discovered a hidden Byte Order Mark character (UTF-8 BOM) that was not supposed to be there. The debug indicated a string length longer than expected.